# KnockoutJS Mapping does not work

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I am hoping someone can take a look at the bwlow code, tell me why it does not work and what to do to fix it.

I have used the ko.mapping plugin inside my project for years, and honestly never truly understood how it worked. Almost seems like magic. Some pages it does (with ajax data coming back) and others like this it fails.

```
                            var aaa = ko.mapping.fromJS({});

                            var ttt = {
                                    "id": 6461,
                                    "displayName": "Test Test",
                                    "emailAddress": "TEST@TEST.com"
                            };

                            console.log(ttt);

                            ko.mapping.fromJS(ttt, {}, aaa);

                            console.log(aaa);
```

If you see output of tt, you get what you expect
Output of aaa is null??

How can this be? I thought mapping was "MAPPING" the JSON to ko.observables?

EDIT:
after getting a fiddle to work, and confirming in a small "lab" thi works, it must have something to do with being inside a DurandalJS page. Maybe the way DurandalJS binds to the VM?

UPDATE:
Ok So my sample above does not provide enough context. Sorry about that. Lets try the following code

```
define(["durandal/app"],
function (app,) {
    return function () {
         var self = this;
         self.aaa = ko.mapping.fromJS({});

          self.myButtonOnWebPageClick = function() {
               var ttt = {
                    "id": 6461,
                    "displayName": "Test Test",
                    "emailAddress": "TEST@TEST.com"
                  };

                  console.log(ttt);

                   ko.mapping.fromJS(ttt, {}, self.aaa);

                   console.log(ko.toJS(self.aaa));
          }

    }
    });
```

some update code above to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I deleted that post. thanks.

Comment: Can you show your durandal code? I think we'd just be guessing in the dark without being able to reproduce the behavior.

Comment: @Jason added some more context to the question

Comment: I set up a sample project in [Glitch](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/solstice-chopper) with your code, but I don't see the behavior you described. I'm guessing that your object is getting set to null somewhere else.